# Accessing JSON values when parsing

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson, fasterxml

I have a file called `persons.json`:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "The Best",
    "email": "thenextbigthing@gmail.com",
    "birthDate": "1981-11-23"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Andy Jr.",
    "email": "usa@gmail.com",
    "birthDate": "1982-12-01"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "JohnDoe",
    "email": "gameover@gmail.com",
    "birthDate": "1990-01-02"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "SomeOne",
    "email": "rucksack@gmail.com",
    "birthDate": "1988-01-22"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Mr. Mxyzptlk",
    "email": "bigman@hotmail.com",
    "birthDate": "1977-08-12"
  }
]
```

I'd like to parse this file into an `ArrayList` with `FasterXML`, possibly with it's `ObjectMapper()` function and then being able to access each value (id, name, etc.) individually as a `String` when iterating through the newly created `ArrayList`. How could I do that? I don't even know what kind of list I could/should use in order to get access to each value individually. I'm kind of stuck here. `List<???>`

Comment: One solution could be to create a Person Class, use ObjectMapper to read your json tree into a ArrayNode and convert each JsonNode of your array into an instance of your Person class using ObjectMapper.readValue(...)

Comment: How can I do that if the type of `id` and `birthDate` in the class are not String but `int` and `LocalDate`.

Comment: Once the data are store in your instances, nothing stops your from converting the values into String using String.valueOf(int) and a DateFormatter for your LocalDate. (Or you can also use a custom json deserializer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all:

> FasterXML uses Jackson underneath to parse/produce json.

Now: to use Jackson, first of all create a container object for the data of your json, which we will call Person

```
public class Person {
  private int id;
  private String name, email;
  @JsonFormat
  (shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
  private Date birthDate;

  //add here getters and setters ...
}
```

At this point, supposing you have `pathToPersonsJsonFile` as a string containing the path to your `persons.json`, you can use your file like this:

```
byte[] jsonData = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(pathToPersonsJsonFile));
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Person[] parsedAsArray = objectMapper.readValue(jsonData, Person[].class); //array
ArrayList<Persons> persons = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(parsedAsArray)); //your list
```

**Note**: `JsonFormat` enables to declare which format that value has on your json.

Comment: I meant that not all of the attributes of my Person class are `String`, `id` is `int` and `birthDate` is `LocalDate`. I can parse successfully when all of the attributes in the class are String, but when `id` is `int` and `birthDate` is `LocalDate`, I'm keep getting errors.

Comment: I have tried: `public Person(String id, String name, String email, String birthDate) {
        this.id = Integer.parseInt(id);
        this.name = name ;
        this.email = email;
        this.birthDate = LocalDate.parse(birthDate);
    }` but it still does not work.

Comment: it uses the setters actually, don;t worry though i will fix my answer depending on this new requirements

Comment: I have fixed the date, but the id should not give you problems as it is a numeric value on the json as well.

Comment: It doesn't matter if I add this line: `@JsonFormat
  (shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")` or not, I'm keep getting the exact same error: " Cannot construct instance of `jsontest.Person` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (File); line: 3, column: 5] (through reference chain: java.lang.Object[][0]) "

Comment: If I also add an empty constructor I'm getting: " Cannot construct instance of `java.time.LocalDate` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('1981-11-23')
 at [Source: (File); line: 6, column: 18] (through reference chain: java.lang.Object[][0]->jsontest.Person["birthDate"]) "

Comment: But why are you using java.time.LocalDate, you should use java.util.Date

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178613/discussion-between-sasieightynine-and-katuiros).

Answer (score 1):

First you should create POJO for storing info:

```
public class Person {
    Long id;
    String name;
    String email;
    @JsonFormat("yyyy-mm-dd")
    Date birthDate;
    ...
}
```

next you should call:

```
List<Person> myObjects = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonInput, new TypeReference<List<Person>>(){});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be enough

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Person> list =  objectMapper.readValue(new File("path_to_persons.json"), new TypeReference<List<Person>>(){});

public class Person {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String birthDate;
   .....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) First create class Person.java

2) Then read the persons.json file and create a JSONArray from it.

3) Then parse as given below:

```
class Person{
        private int id;
        private String name;
        private String email;
        private String birthDate;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public String getBirthDate() {
            return birthDate;
        }

        public void setBirthDate(String birthDate) {
            this.birthDate = birthDate;
        }
    }


    public List<Person> getPersonList(JSONArray dataArray){
        List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i<dataArray.length(); i++){
            try {
                JSONObject personJsonObject = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Person person = new Person();
                if(personJsonObject.has("id") && !personJsonObject.isNull("id")){
                    person.setId(personJsonObject.getInt("id"));
                }
                if(personJsonObject.has("name") && !personJsonObject.isNull("name")){
                    person.setName(personJsonObject.getString("name"));
                }
                if(personJsonObject.has("email") && !personJsonObject.isNull("email")){
                    person.setEmail(personJsonObject.getString("email"));
                }
                if(personJsonObject.has("birthDate") && !personJsonObject.isNull("birthDate")){
                    person.setBirthDate(personJsonObject.getString("birthDate"));
                }
                personList.add(person);
            }catch (JSONException e){

            }
        }
        return personList;
    }
```

4) Then use this list wherever you want.